# Encrypt All User Defined SQL Server Functions using C#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to Encrypt all user defined functions of SQL Server (Table valued, Scalar valued, Aggregate) using C# program.

I already did the same for Stored procedures.

But I couldn't find the class for Functions.

Please tell how can I Encrypt the Functions?

```
                StoredProcedure sp;
            sp = new StoredProcedure();
            sp = db.StoredProcedures[i];
            if (!sp.IsSystemObject)// Exclude System stored procedures
            {
                if (!sp.IsEncrypted) // Exclude already encrypted stored procedures
                {
                    string text = "";// = sp.TextBody;
                    sp.TextMode = false;
                    sp.IsEncrypted = true;
                    sp.TextMode = true;
                    sp.Alter();

                    lblMsg.Text= sp.Name; // display name of the encrypted SP.                        
                    sp = null;
                    text = null;
                }


            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far about your program? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Aggregates can only be implemented as CLR functions. As such, there's no encryption options in T-SQL since the code isn't visible anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below code, my problem was resolved

```
for (int j = 0; j < db.UserDefinedFunctions.Count; j++)
        {
            UserDefinedFunction udf;

            udf = new UserDefinedFunction();

            udf = db.UserDefinedFunctions[j];
            if (!udf.IsSystemObject)// Exclude System User Defind Functions
            {
                if (!udf.IsEncrypted) // Exclude already encrypted User Defind Functions
                {
                    string text = "";// = sp.TextBody;
                    udf.TextMode = false;
                    udf.IsEncrypted = true;
                    udf.TextMode = true;
                    udf.Alter();

                    lblMsg.Text = udf.Name; // display name of the encrypted User Defind Functions.                        
                    udf = null;
                    text = null;
                }


            }
        }
```